# What is the Apple recommendation for creating component and using modifiers in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I would like to ask what is the Apple recommendation on using modifiers and creating reusable view on SwiftUI 
for example we can use buttonStyle and inherit it to create custom style for a button also we can create a custom reusable view for the same purpose.

here is a code example

```
/* 
this is the style for a gradient button
*/
struct GradientButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .padding()
            .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.red, Color.orange]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
            .cornerRadius(15.0)
    }
}
```

```
/* 
and here we declare it
*/
Button(action: {
 print("Button action")
}) {
 HStack {
     Image(systemName: "bookmark.fill")
     Text("Bookmark")
 }
}.buttonStyle(GradientButtonStyle())
```

also we can use this way

```
struct ButtonView: View {
    let Action: () -> Void
     var title = "Title"
    var body: some View {
          HStack {
        Image(systemName: "bookmark.fill")
        Text(self.title)
    }.onTapGesture {
       Action()
    }
 .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            .padding()
            .background(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.red, Color.orange]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
            .cornerRadius(15.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're looking for Apple SwiftUI programming recommendations in general, you may find some at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui or https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/. Not sure if you'll find something official about your use case, but I recommend following the tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of `Button` in particular, you should use `Button` with a style if possible, rather than reimplementing it from scratch. When you use `Button`, the accessibility system knows it's a button. When you implement it from scratch, the accessibility system doesn't know what it is.

Comment: it's make a sense